# I can't get my image slideshow to work using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, timer, document.write

I am trying to create a simple image slideshow type thing with the Javascript code below, but what it is doing is displaying the first image in the webpage with everything else, then after 5 seconds clearing the page and displaying the *same* image, then again every 5 seconds except it doesn't clear the page anymore.

The JavaScript:

```
var waiPics=new Array();
waiPics[0]='images/path.jpg';
waiPics[1]='images/gorse.jpg';
waiPics[2]='images/stream.jpg';
waiPics[3]='images/pines.jpg';
waiPics[4]='images/stump.jpg';

var time;

function timeUp() {
    delete document.write();
    nextPic();
}



function nextPic() {
    var picNum=0;
if (picNum = waiPics.length) {
    picNum=0;
}
else {
    picNum++;
} 
    document.write('<img src="'+waiPics[picNum]+'" title="Waipahihi" alt="Waipahihi">');
    time=setTimeout("timeUp()",5000);
}
```

The HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- Begin
nextPic();
//  End -->
</script>
```

Im not very experienced with Javascript, so thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

picNum will always be zero because it is declared inside a function and will set to zero every time the function is called.  Even if you fix this, your condition is wrong:

```
if (picNum = waiPics.length) {
```

The conditional should be:

```
if (picNum === waiPics.length) {
```

The single = sign assigns the length to picNum, then converts to a boolean.  The array length is nonzero, so it becomes true value.  It then resets to zero every time.

Consider using [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com) to check your code for errors and to suggest improvements.  It flagged the issue:

```
"Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment."
if (picNum = waiPics.length) {
```

In fact, after using JSLint on your code and examining its suggestions, I would use something more like this:

```
// New array creation syntax
var waiPics = ['images/path.jpg', 'images/gorse.jpg', 'images/stream.jpg', 'images/pines.jpg', 'images/stump.jpg'];

var picNum = 0;  // Declare outside inner function so its value is preserved
var myDiv = document.getElementById("ssdiv");  // Get a div element to insert picture into

function nextPic() {
    if (picNum === waiPics.length) {    // Proper comparison
        picNum = 0;
    } else {
        picNum += 1;
    }

    // Set picture into div element without evil document.write
    myDiv.innerHTML = '<img src="' + waiPics[picNum] + '" title="Waipahihi" alt="Waipahihi">';

    // No longer need timeUp; also don't use eval syntax
    setTimeout(nextPic, 5000);
}
```

Assigning innerHTML avoids various problems with document.write and also does not require your page to refresh to change slideshow images.  Also note other comments.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. Do I keep the <script> thing in my html, putting it inside the new div?

Comment: It does display different images, but when i did the div thing, it just completely disappeared O_o

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the comparison operator ('==') instead of assigning ('=') here:

```
//if (picNum = waiPics.length) {
if (picNum == waiPics.length) {
```

Comment: He should be using ===, not ==, which is a conversion compare.

Comment: I do not see much difference in this specific case. Both operators will work fine.

Comment: JSLint will flag any use of == as bad because it converts types before comparing.  For example, ""==0 is true, while ""===0 is false.  When you use == instead of ===, you get unintended side effects that are the source of many bugs.  I started out scoffing this and using ==, and it got me into trouble so many times that I relented and never use it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this example...

http://jsfiddle.net/DaveAlger/eNxuJ/1/

---

to get your own slideshow working, copy and paste the following html into any text file and save it as `slides.html`

you can add any number of `<img>` elements inside the `<div class="slideshow">`

enjoy!

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="slideshow">
        <img src="http://davealger.info/i/1.jpg" />
        <img src="http://davealger.info/i/2.bmp" />
        <img src="http://davealger.info/i/3.png" />
    </div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('.slideshow img:gt(0)').hide();
            setInterval(function(){$('.slideshow :first-child').fadeOut(2000).next('img').fadeIn(2000).end().appendTo('.slideshow');}, 4000);
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        .slideshow { position:relative; }
        .slideshow img { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```